# Installing Samsung m2020 printer

Tags: drivers

I have found relevant PPD files but it gives me this when I try to print
Printer 'Samsung-M2020-Series' requires the '/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl' program but it is not currently installed.

Comment: Is there a file `/opt/smfp-common/printer/bin/rastertospl` on your system? In that case, create a link from it to the missing file, as follows: `sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/printer/bin/rastertospl /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Samsung M2070, tried all the commands to make it work with ppd file, but the printer did not work and I had the same message.

The solution was, that I deleted the printer via `localhost:631` and downloaded the samsung drivers again. I left them in downloads folder and I followed these [instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/samsungprinters) to install it properly. The printer started to work immediately after the installation finished. Before, I used different instructions and it seems that it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the [*Samsung Print Driver for Linux*](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/samsung-xpress-sl-m2020-laser-printer-series/16462592) archive and extract it ([Samsung sold its *Printing Business Unit* to HP/Hewlett-Packard around 2016](https://news.samsung.com/global/samsung-electronics-announces-divestment-of-printing-business-unit-and-nomination-of-jay-y-lee-to-the-board-of-directors), hence Samsung printer drivers are now provided by HP).
- Extract the archive, `cd uld/`, then `sudo ./install.sh` .
- Agree to the licence agreements; the installer will then ask you for tweaking firewall rules - I declined here.
- The installer will install files under `/opt/samsung/` and `/opt/smfp/` ("Samsung/smart multi-function printer"), as well as create a couple of symlinks (`/usr/share/cups/model/uld-samsung`, `/usr/share/ppd/uld-samsung`, `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl` ...) in order for CUPS and the OS printing infrastructure to discover the installed Samsung "drivers".
- In case there are still problems, check for error messages in `/var/log/cups/error_log`. In my particular case, I was missing a shared library which Samsung's cups-filter `rastertospl` depends on. See https://serverfault.com/a/1151813/127106 for how to identify such missing shared libraries and how to install them.